# Regrounding Zero Based ColumnSeries in Apache/Adobe Flex

Tags: apache, apache-flex, charts, adobe, data-visualization

I have [tweeted an image](http://t.co/2dhqeVDz4j) illustrating the problem with Flex ColumnSeries on a PlotChart when trying to overlay one on top of another.

Essentially, it can display one series alright, two or more OK on initialization, but after a bit of manipulation (in the user session), the columns lose their sense of where zero is, and begin to float (these series have no minfield, thus zero is their starting point). FWIW: the axis for these columns is on the right, but that can change given the type of data displayed.

The app this is for allows users to turn multiple series of multiple plotting styles on and off, change visual parameters, and even the order in which the series stack on top of each other -- just to give you an idea of what's going on.

Due to how dynamic this all is, I am doing most of the code in ActionScript.

So the questions are:

1. Is this fixable? Googling around has provided no insights, regardless of inquiry.
2. Is there a refresh function or equivalent within PlotChart/CartesianCharts that may help?
3. May this not be a problem with the chart canvas, but more of the axis which the series points to? or the series itself?

If it has not been made clear already: I am lost on this. The issue I have known about for ~a year now was first discovered on a Beta version of the app I am working on now, but it took a while for it to surface in an average user session. As the complexity of the app has grown (by client demand), the issue takes a lot less time to surface.

The issue also occurs on all versions of Flex I have used: 4.5, 4.6, 4.9... etc.

Please help, or offer pointers. Thanks!

Comment: Might have fixed it, although it requires regenerating the series every time it is called by the user.

Comment: I'll leave this question unanswered if someone comes up with another insight.